# How to find people to help translate my open source project?

Tags: javascript, localization, translate

I'm a big StackOverflow fan, but I think this question belongs here, correct me if I'm wrong.
So basically I'm trying to localize [my plugin](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) in as many languages as possible. I posted a section on the docs to reach people that wants to help translating but I only got one contributor that attached a German translation. So far I got 4 languages, English, Spanish, French and German.

So my question is, how do you guys translate your projects? Where do you find people interested in contributing? Does anybody use Google translate to do the job?

Comment: Where I worked we've used translation services, we send them an excel spreadsheet and they send it back with translations in columns right next to the text. I have no idea how they found the company that did it for us, but I know these companies exist. They presumably employed a grip of translators and charged per translation or something of the nature.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: Ouch. I would not want to do translation that way.  Even if you have a really good bilingual person acting as translator, there are still lots of cases where a term is ambiguous, and without context you can get it wrong and lead to [mistakes in the final product that look really silly.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EitherWorldDominationOrSomethingAboutBananas)

Comment: This is off topic because issues with translation of documents or resources are not significant nor unique to software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really only two ways to get someone to do work for you.  Either you pay them for it, or you get them to want to do it without being paid.

Assuming you're not looking to hire translators, your best bet is to do exactly what you're doing--make it known among your users that you're looking for localization--and then try to increase the size of your user base.  The more people you have using the program, the more likely you are to run into someone who has the skills and the desire to help you out.